# Toolbar icon for Create Scala Class for Scala-Plugin for Eclipse nowhere to be found

Tags: eclipse, scala, toolbar, scala-ide

In my toolbar, I have my green 'C' button to create a new Java Class. But I have no option for creating a new Scala class (on my toolbar. I can still do it manually). I went to `Window > Customize Perspective`, and under `Java Element Creation`, I see `Class...`, which is checked (allowing for Create Java Class icon in my toolbar), but nothing about Scala classes anywhere. I went to every tab, dropped down every menu, and nothing. When I do use the 'Create Class' icon, it creates a Java class. Is there any way of getting a 'Create Scala Class' option for my toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this feature is not currently part of the Scala support.
It should not be too hard to add, it is mainly configuration. You should open a feature request, or better contribute the change.

Personally, I never noticed these buttons in the toolbar :) I use `shift+alt+n` if I want a short list of 'new' wizard. This list is configurable in `Window > Customize Perspective > Shortcuts`.

Comment: Aw :( I always use the toolbar (especially the little drop-down menu for the icons). Easier to quickly create a new enum, class or interface. For some reason, there are a ton of things listed when I go to `File > New...`, and I end up having to scroll down for `Scala Class`. I'll try out the shortcut though, thanks for the tip :D